# Google Sheets Function. Count responses from multiple different columns with same header

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google form that collects data and is sorted into a table that has repeated headers (red, blue, green, red, blue, green) and under each of these headers there are 8 rows that will either say yes or no.

This grid is filled out multiple times a day when doing checks on the production line (red, blue, green are different shifts). I want to count all the "Yes" responses under each shift to workout a percentage of performance for each shift (colour).

EDIT
I am aware I can just add together loads of COUNTIF functions but I am looking for a more elegant way

I tried using a QUERY function but the COUNT function doesn't seem to like to count from multiple columns (at least not the way I've tried). I am unsure how to do COUNTIF with multiple ranges in one function as well so cannot get that to work either.

I assume the QUERY function can do it, but I am unsure how

Answer (score 0):

```
=bycol(H4:J4,lambda(y, sum(BYCOL(A1:F5,LAMBDA(x,sumproduct((array_constrain(x,1,1)=y)*(x="yes")))))))
```

Where `H4:J4` is colors you want to count and `A1:F5` is whole data table with headers:

[image]